# Github markdown escape checkbox mark

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I am pretty new to markdown and I couldn't find an answer to this problem:
On github, when doing: `* \[X]`, a checkbox checked is appearing. Is there any way to get this output (the star is the puce of the list) `* [X]` ?
I could try to use an unicode char to represent a similar X, but I'd rather have something more clean.

Thank you.

Comment: On my markdown, I have two lines which output two different things :
`* \[X]: Plugin for firefox` Which work correctly even without backslack, and the other one : `* \[X] [TamperData]: modify and tamper HTTP requests` which does'nt work, `[TamperData]` is a link referenced later in the markdown.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `- [X] Sample` for getting a checked checkbox - I didn't get one typing `\[X] Sample` nor `[X] Sample`.

If you want to escape that, you can just do `\- [X] Sample`.

I've just tested that using the Preview tab, and it works. If the actual result is different, that should be an issue.

Comment: I have updated my question. This is in a list with a star, you can check the page [there](https://github.com/Laxa/HackingTools).

Comment: I have tried `* \[X]` and `*\* [X]` and they both don't work (at least in the preview editor).